# Can you use a boolean in a POST request in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I tried to use a boolean in the dict for the formdata parameter in scrapy.FormRequest() because the POST request requires a boolean. Scrapy wouldn't let me use a boolean in the dict. So I tried to use the string "false" instead but it doesn't seem to work and I get this error after the POST request:

```
2019-12-11 21:48:55 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://passport.twitch.tv/login>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2019-12-11 21:48:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Is there a way to use a boolean in the POST request? And am I getting the error because I'm not using the right formdata?

Comment: booleans in requests are just strings. you could try "False" and see. 
Are you sure it's even a boolean ?  where did you see the formdata ?

Comment: I saw it in the developer tools in network in chrome when I entered the form in my browser. This is for a login so the website probably doesn't want me using a bot. But if the formdata is the same as when I did it in my browser it should work? I did change my user agent

Comment: It’s not just the form data, the headers (cookies included) could play a role in the request.